# $\det A = a_{1 , 1}A_{1 , 1} - a_{1 , 2}A_{1 , 2} + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} a_{1 , n}A_{1 , n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$A = (a_{ij})$ is a square matrix  of order $n$ . It's determinant will be $a_{1 , 1}A_{1 , 1} - a_{1 , 2}A_{1 , 2} + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} a_{1 , n}A_{1 , n}$. Here $A_{i , j}$ is the co-factor of $a_{i , j}$.

The definition of determinant is following.

[image]

I was trying to prove it only from the definition of determinant . I was not allowed to use any other result than the definition of determinant.

But I am not being able to do that. Can anyone please help me to do this ?

Comment: Is your definition of determinant the sum over permutations?

Comment: Yes...................................... @Phicar

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a permutation $\sigma$ on $n$ elements. Iterate over the value of $\sigma (1).$
You will start something like
$$det(A)=\sum _{\sigma \in S_n}(-1)^{|inv(\sigma )|}\prod _{i=1}^{n}A_{i,\sigma (i)}=\sum _{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\sum _{\substack{\tau \in S_{n-1}\\\sigma = \sigma(1)\tau}}(-1)^{|inv(\tau)|}A_{1,k}\prod _{i=2}^{n}A_{i,\sigma(i)}.$$
In the formula, $S_{n-1}$ is used instead of the permutations of $[n]\setminus \{\sigma (1)\}$ but they are in bijection.
It is important to notice that the sign of a permutation is $(-1)^{|inv(\sigma)|},$ where $inv(\sigma)=\{(i,j):i<j \text{ and }\sigma _i>\sigma _j\}.$ and if you fix $k=\sigma(1)$ then you already know that the inversion contains, at least, $k-1$ elements i.e., $(1,\sigma(1)),(2,\sigma(1))\cdots (\sigma(1)-1,\sigma(1)).$
Which part of the corresponds to the co-factor and how is the inversion set that defines the sign gets modified by fixing $\sigma(1)=k$? 
As an example, take $\sigma = 31254,$ then $k=\sigma(1)=3$ and when you take out $3$ you end up with the sequence $1254$ that can be though as a permutation $\tau = 1243$ that respects the order of this. Show that $|inv(\sigma)|=k-1+|inv(\tau)|.$

Comment: I did not understand anything. @Phicar

Comment: @sani I have edited it. Let me know what is confusing.

Comment: Can you tell me what are inv , what ? You have used so many notations. Can you do it in simple language ? @Phicar

Comment: @cmi inv is a permutation statistics in which you count how many times you inverted a pair of elements. For example, $|inv(123)|=0$ because it is the identity, you did not swap anything, but $|inv(15324)|=3+1=4$ because $5$ has $3$ smaller elements on the right, and $3$ has one.

Answer (score 1):

Given two sets $X, Y$, let $B(X,Y)$ denote the (possibly empty) set of all bijections $X\to Y$. For $M_n = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ we let $\mathfrak S_n = B(M_n,M_n)$ denote the set of all permutations of $M_n$. For $k \in M_n$ let $M_n^k = M_n \setminus \{k\}$ and let $b_k : M_{n-1} \to M_n^k$ denote the unique order preserving bijection. Explicitly $b_k(i) = i$ for $i < k$ and $b_k(i) = i+1$ for $i \ge k$.

We have $\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n} \left(\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)} \right)$.

Let $\bar A_{1,k}$ denote the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$-matrix obtained from $A$ by deleting the first row and the $k$-th column. Then $A_{1,k} = \det \bar A_{1,k}$. We have $\bar A_{1,k} = (\bar a_{i,j})$ with $\bar a_{i,j} = a_{b_1(i),b_k(j)}$.

Define $\mathfrak S_n^{1,k} =\{ \sigma \in \mathfrak S_n \mid \sigma(1) = k \}$. Then
$$\det A = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{1,k}\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n^{1,k}} \left(\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=2}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)} \right) .$$
There is an obvious bijection $c_{1,k} : B(M_n^1, M_n^k) \to \mathfrak S_n^{1,k}$. Thus
$$f_{1,k} : \mathfrak S_{n-1} \to \mathfrak S_n^{1,k}, f_{1,k}(\tau) = c_{1,k}(b_k \tau b_1^{-1})$$
is a bijection. Explicitly $\bar \tau = f_{1,k}(\tau)$ is given by
$$\bar \tau(i) = \begin{cases} k & i = 1 \\ b_k(\tau(i-1)) & i > 1 \end{cases}$$

For a permutation $\omega \in \mathfrak S_m$ we have $\operatorname{sgn}(\omega) = (-1)^{N(\omega)}$, where $N(\omega)$ is the number of inversions in $\omega$, i.e. the number of elements of the set $I(\omega) = \{ (i,j) \mid i,j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}, i < j , \omega(i) > \omega(j) \}$.

Let us count the pairs $(i,j)$,  $1 \le i < j \le n$, which belong to $I(\bar \tau)$.

Case 1. $i = 1$.

Then the inversion condition $k = \bar \tau(1) > \bar \tau(j)$ is satisfied iff $\tau(j-1) < k$. Among $j =2,\ldots,n$ there are exactly $k-1$ numbers such that $\tau(j-1) < k$ (since  $\tau$ is a bijection on $M_{n-1}$).

Case 2. $i > 1$.

We have $\bar \tau(i) > \bar \tau(j)$ iff $b_k(\tau(i-1)) > b_k(\tau(j-1))$. Since $b_k$ is order preserving, i.e. *strictly increasing*, this is equivalent to $\tau(i-1) > \tau(j-1)$. This shows that the number of inversions of $\bar \tau$ which have the form $(i,j)$ with $i > 1$ is exactly $N(\tau)$.

Cases 1. and 2. prove $N(\bar \tau) = N(\tau) + k - 1$. Hence
$$\det A = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{1,k}\sum_{\tau \in \mathfrak S_{n-1}} \left(\operatorname{sgn}(\bar \tau) \prod_{i=2}^n a_{i,\bar \tau(i)} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{1,k}\sum_{\tau \in \mathfrak S_{n-1}} \left((-1)^{k-1}\operatorname{sgn}(\tau) \prod_{i=2}^n a_{i,\bar \tau(i)} \right) \\ = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}a_{1,k}\sum_{\tau \in \mathfrak S_{n-1}} \left(\operatorname{sgn}(\tau) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} a_{i+1,\bar \tau(i+1)} \right).$$
But $i+1 = b_1(i)$ and $\bar \tau(i+1) = b_k(\tau(i))$ and therefore
$$\det A = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}a_{1,k} \det \bar A_{1,k} = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}a_{1,k} A_{1,k} .$$